# Convert NSTimeInterval to NSString in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nstimeinterval

How to covert the NSTimeInterval to NSString? I have

```
NSTimeInterval  today = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

I have to give "today" as input as NSString.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

NSTimeInterval is just a double type so you can convert it to string using +stringWithFormat: method

```
NSTimeInterval  today = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *intervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", today];
```

Comment: Thanks ,i was trying with %@ instead of %f.

Comment: %@ is only for objects. And moreover, objects that respond to the `-description` message.

Comment: @jer, or localizedDescription it seems... anyway description method is defined in NSObject so all its descendants respond to it

Comment: All descendents of NSObject do yes, but descendents of NSProxy do not. Sorry, I wasn't being explicit.

Comment: actually you made a good point - as most classes inherit from NSObject and respond to -description: method it is so easy to lose care and accidentally call it on those objects which do not respond

Comment: What's the point of typedefing NSTimeInterval if I have to know what it stands for to log the value of this type. It looks like a breach in abstraction to me. Isn't there a truly platform-independent way to deal with typedefs?

Answer (score 3):

```
-(NSString*)formattedDuration:(NSTimeInterval)interval{
    NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute;
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorPad;
    NSString *string = [formatter stringFromTimeInterval:interval];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
    // output: 0:20:34
    return string;
}
```