# timeIntervalSince1970 crashing with NSUserDefaults

Tags: crash, nsstring, nsdate, nsuserdefaults, nstimeinterval

I'm trying to show a UIALertView every 4 days. But getting a crash because:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString timeIntervalSince1970]:
```

I tried using different approaches like the following code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4278151/1014564 resulting in the same crash.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDate *firstLaunchDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"timeStamp"];
NSDate *dateNow = [[NSDate alloc] init];

if (!firstLaunchDate){

    NSString *nowTimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];

    [defaults setObject:nowTimestamp            forKey:@"timeStamp"];
    [defaults synchronize];


} else if (([dateNow timeIntervalSince1970] - [firstLaunchDate timeIntervalSince1970]) > 86400*4){

 ///UIAlertView Here..

}
```

Answers appreciated and will be accepted. I know it's probably a simple mistake, I'm past the point of sleepy atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nowTimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:...];
[defaults setObject:nowTimestamp forKey:@"timeStamp"];
```

then

```
NSDate *firstLaunchDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"timeStamp"];
```

So you're basically setting an `NSString` in the user defaults, but you expect to get back an `NSDate`. Since `NSUserDefaults` ain't magic, that won't happen. If you want to store a date, store it using

```
[defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];
```

and **only then** you can use `timeIntervalSince1970` on the object you get back from `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Scary, I was just about to ask you if ya wanted some SO points on twitter. Thanks man! I'll accept when it lets me. :)

Comment: @CokePokes No problem :) That's why I love Objective-C's dynamism: it gives me SO reputation. :P